# How to style component in React Native dynamically?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-stylesheet

I'm using the `AirbnbRating` component from [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ratings) package.

The problem is with styling it dynamically as I'm using a global style file and defining all my styles there.

I need to change the `size` prop of `AirbnbRating` from that `styles.js` file.

Here is my code

```
<AirbnbRating
    onFinishRating={this.ratingCompleted}
    showRating={false}
    size={20}
    selectedColor="#0022FF"
    starContainerStyle={{
       alignSelf: "flex-start",
       backgroundColor: 'transparent',
       marginLeft: -3,
    }}
 />
```

In this line `size={20}` I need to do something like this

```
size={styles.ratingSize}
```

Is there a way to do it ?

EDIT:

My styles file is like this

```
export default {
    contain: {
         flex: 1,
    },
    ratingSize: {
         //what should this be ? 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to do :

ratingSize: {
width: 20,
}

Then styles.ratzingSize.width

You just need the value for it anyway.

Comment: What should path contain ?

Comment: Path to your style that you want to use.

Comment: But in style there is defined propterties like width, height, color, etc , The prop is called `size`

Comment: style.path.size?

Comment: I guess there is a missunderstanding here, I will edit my question with my style file so you get an idea